# What does ? mean in Weka?

Tags: weka

In Weka, after having preprocessed my data, I ran the multilayer perceptron function on my data. However, upon running my data, some of the entries have a "?" in the TP rate category. What does that mean? Why does it occur?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A ? in the input data is missing data.
A ? in the output means the result can't be calculated.

Since you mention TP, this means TP cannot be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

This was [answered](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/hyperkitty/list/wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz/message/C2WJUIX6V4GC7ECMWW2XHKUQHTUDTGBK/) by Eibe Frank on the Weka mailing list:

*That means the corresponding value is undefined. For example, precision is defined as TP / PP, where TP Is the number of true positives and PP is the number of instances that are predicted to be positive (for whichever class is currently considered the “positive” class). If PP is zero, there will be a division by zero, which yields a “?” in the output.*